# TSQL OLE (com) Objects

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, com, ole, sqlclr

Are there any inherent problems with calling an ole object from tsql? I have been posed with a problem that I would like to solve solely using a stored procedure, is there anything I need to worry about with using a ole object as opposed to writing it in a clr based language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you can't do it as a set-based operation first, remember to free them when you're done, and remember that this isn't going to be at all portable (but then neither would the clr code).

Answer (score 2):

Com objects are mostly native code, if you call something that has a memory leak you could cause problems down the road